# WPF storing strings in resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I would like to store string from example

```xml
<label x:name="label" Content="something that be displayed" />
```

But i don't want to hardcode the value Content in XAML and instead i would like to create a dictionary where this string will be stored.
How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a string property in your data context, viewModel or code behind and bind your label to that property.

```
<Label x:Name="Label" Content="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
```

Sorry for not adding this as a comment (but I don't have enough rep).